# KeyError in append dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, exception, keyerror

I have large peace of data, iterate true this in loop and append values by key:

```
for q in my_dict:
output.append({"roomsCount": q['roomsCount'], "totalArea": float(q['totalArea']), 
"floorNumber": q['floorNumber'],"price": int(q['bargainTerms']['price']), ...})
```

Sometimes i got : **KeyError: 'roomsCount'** or **KeyError: 'totalArea'** etc. if key doesn't exist.

How i can set default value for any key in case if this key not exist? Without repeat try: except for each of my key:value pairs

Comment: You could use [`dict.get(key, default_value)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_get.htm)

Comment: See `dict.get` and `dict.setdefault`

Comment: It's probably unrelated to your error, but it looks like your `my_dict` variable is misleadingly named. If you iterate over a dictionary, you get the keys. It looks like `my_dict` is a list of dictionaries (or some similar kind of iterable).

Comment: Thanks, solved issue

Answer (score 1):

> How i can set default value for any key in case if this key not exist?

The [dict.setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method is likely what you want here:

```
d = {'hits': 10, 'gold': 5}
print( d.setdefault('weapons', 0) )
print( d.setdefault('hits', 10) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding dict.get, thanks for comments. My code

```
for q in mydict:
        output.append(
            {"roomsCount": q.get('roomsCount', 0), "totalArea": float(q.get('totalArea', 0)), "floorNumber": q.get('floorNumber',0),
             "price": int(q.get('bargainTerms''price',0))...})
```